# Leaflet Control Search and GeoServer WFS

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, search

Maybe someone could help me how to use plugin [Leaflet Control Search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) with WFS from GeoServer. The control is added to the map. But when I try to search a single feature with this plugin, the WFS response with full list of all features. How should I use the Leaflet Control Search to get ony one, searched feature from WFS. I'm quite new in Leaflet and GeoServer. Please, help. Here is what I made:

```
mapid.addControl(new L.Control.Search({
   url: "http://localhost:8000/geoserver/przejazdy/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=przejazdy:lokalizacje&outputFormat=application/json"
   propertyLoc: ['wsp_lat', 'wsp_lon'],
   propertyName: 'nr_id',
   zoom: 16,
   markerLocation: true
}));
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! Code is missing from your question. Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: I see this open issue https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/issues/43 but I do not understand if it works